# Making a multi step form with 4 steps. If I come back from step 3 to 2, how do I show the data saved from step 2?

Tags: html, angularjs, angular

For example,

say the user is on step 2, and enters his name in `<input type="text" class="form-control input-xl" ngModel name="firstName">`

He goes to step 3, but now wants to come back to step 2.  I have the data saved in my form object, `formData.stepTwo.firstName`.  How do I show this in the input instead of blank?

I am using angular 2.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-xl" [(ngModel)]="formData.stepTwo.firstName" name="firstName">
```

Comment: Thanks.  The thing is, I'm using the angular 2 forms to use a field set and ngModelGroup.  So, that's why I just had the `ngModel` there.  I used your way and it seems to work fine.  Do you think there's any issues in doing that?

Comment: No I don't think there's anything wrong with doing it this way. Using ngModel without specifying a value is used for one-way data binding. Which is why you weren't seeing changes reflected when coming back to step 2.